# How to reduce the dbf size in shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, dbf

**Edit of post:** ***I decided to edit the post to answer the comments below / and to change the example of shapefile that I used originally.***

I am working with QGIS and I have a shapefile with points (that represent coordinates on the map). The shp size is not that big but the dbf size is bigger! The dbf contains all the labels of the coordinates.

For example these are the sizes of shapefile. :
[image]

There is one field which has labels of the coordinates. And there are 958876 points/attributes in total.

[image]

The **dbf is 233 MB** & the **shp is 33 MB.**
Is there any way to reduce the dbf size without ruining the data?

Do I need to change the labels from string to integer? Maybe the issue is the something to do with formatting?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120782/discussion-on-question-by-blue-cat-how-to-reduce-the-dbf-size-in-shapefile-in-qg).